# Reset the background color of a Cell in pysheet

Tags: pygsheets

Trying to reset the color of a linked cell.

Looking at a cell without color, the color attribute is (None, None, None, None)

So I tried:

```
cell.color = (None, None, None, None)
```

and

```
cell.color = None
```

Both raise

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Is reseting the color supported by pysheets?

Comment: You are right, there is no way to reset from the api. we can only set colors. But isnt reset same as setting to white?

Comment: @Nithin yes in most cases (we ended up doing that), but we have some automation which need to consider white and empty being the same now. No complaint from anyone people doing sheets in dark mode yet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reset the color you can do :

```
cell.color = ()
```

Comment: Elegant, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Google Sheets API [you need to pass a RGBA value](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#Color), which means that you need to pass in values that are acceptable for the RGBA spectrum (0-255).

Try `cell.color = (0,0,0,0)`, the fourth digit in the sequence specifies the alpha channel to be transparent.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but (0,0,0,0) or (0,0,0,1) ends up as black. On the other end of the spectrum (1, 1, 1, 1 or 0) ends up as white. No reset through, might be a limit from Google APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Jon, it was worth a try.